# How do I properly loop this code? I can't get it to work. Still very new to coding

Tags: python, loops

```
import random

randomOne = random.randint(1,10)
    print(randomOne)
randomTwo = random.randint(1,10)
    print(randomTwo)

b = randomTwo * 2
while b != randomOne:
    print("Your first number is not a multiple of the second number!")
x = input('Press Enter to try again.')


randomOne = random.randint(1,10)
print(randomOne)
randomTwo = random.randint(1,10)
print(randomTwo)

if randomTwo * 2 == randomOne:
    print("Your first number is a multiple of the second number!")
```

I can't get this code to loop when the second number is not a multiple of the first number. And also, how do I make it so that the program finishes once the condition is true, i.e., the second number IS a multiple of the first number.

Comment: if b really isn't equal to randomone, you'll just have an infinite loop - you never change the loop conditions while inside the loop, so the loop could never end.

Comment: You need to specify a way to get out of the loop, put randomOne and randomTwo inside of the loop perhaps?

Comment: Please describe what the program is supposed to do.  You have no comments, and the text in your user instructions doesn't match what the code does.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, unlike most other programming languages, code indentation matters. The following should work since indentations have been fixed. Also, you'll need to recalculate the value of `b` in the while loop, that way the loop will eventually fail.

```
import random

randomOne = random.randint(1,10)
print(randomOne)
randomTwo = random.randint(1,10)
print(randomTwo)

b = randomTwo * 2
while b != randomOne:
    print("Your first number is not a multiple of the second number!")
    x = input('Press Enter to try again.')

    randomOne = random.randint(1,10)
    print(randomOne)
    randomTwo = random.randint(1,10)
    print(randomTwo)
    b = randomTwo * 2

# No need to check if it is a multiple since it must be to break the loop
print("Your first number is a multiple of the second number!")
```

If your goal is to find a combination of two numbers where the first is truly a multiple of the second you could try something like this:

```
import random

randomOne = random.randint(1,10)
print(randomOne)
randomTwo = random.randint(1,10)
print(randomTwo)

b = randomOne / randomTwo
# If b is an integer, then it divided evenly
while b != int(b):
    print("Your first number is not a multiple of the second number!")
    x = input('Press Enter to try again.')

    randomOne = random.randint(1,10)
    print(randomOne)
    randomTwo = random.randint(1,10)
    print(randomTwo)
    b = randomOne / randomTwo

if randomTwo * 2 == randomOne:
    print("Your first number is a multiple of the second number!")
```